# Two JavaScripts on one Web App

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I'm creating a web app for a charity and I have found two JavaScript functions I want to use.

The first is an 'Add to Home Screen for iPhone', which I have put on my web app and works, and it can be found here: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

The second script I want to use collapsible drop down buttons to hide the text that the charity want to use. I have found the JavaScript code, and I know that I to use the code below:

```
<body onload="dothat();dothis()">

<!------------SCRIPT 1-------------->
<script>
function dothis(){
"
"
"
}
</script>
<!------------END OF SCRIPT 1--->

<!-------------SCRIPT 2---------------->
<script>
function dothat(){
"
"
"
}
</script>
<!------------END OF SCRIPT 2------>

</body>
```

how do I use both scripts on one web app page?

Comment: You're using jQuery. You should be using `$(document).ready(...)` instead of hardcoding things into your body's `onload` event. The code you've posted *is* how you would do what you're trying to do. What about it isn't working? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If they are bigger functions maybe you should link them in the html head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
```